# Running comprehensive speed tests on a drive

Tags: hard-disk, storage, benchmark

I'm wondering if anybody knows of any free packages, scripts or command line tools that can report a comprehensive speed test on a drive (e.g. generating random data, and testing how long it takes to transfer it). The drive can be internal, external or on the network.

Answer (score 3):

That would be a job for [`bonnie++`](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/). There are other benchmark tools of course but this one does exactly what you listed and is sort of a de-facto starting place for read/write bench-marking disks.